# When applying code formatting, how can I see the actual changes made by IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

My team likes to have one consistent code style. We've all set our respective IntelliJ formatters to use the same style "scheme".

Right now, I use <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for formatting, and get a pop-up saying the job is done:

[image: "Formatted n lines / Removed m imports"]

It doesn't show the exact changes, just provides a summary. The alternate command, with <kbd>Shift</kbd>, provides some config options, but doesn't show the results either.

Sometimes I want to see the actual changes that the formatter makes. Usually this is to see if there are places where a complicated line or block could benefit from the formatter being turned off.

Is there some way to get basically a diff of the file, before and after formatting? Short of saving a copy of the old version before every formatting and manually diffing them, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Local History** feature or the version control to get the diff of the file.

- [Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html)
- [Comparing files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/comparing-files-and-folders.html)

[image: Local History]

Answer (score 1):

you can select the entire class, and right click on it and click "Local History -> Show history for selection" it will compare the two versions of the class and show you the differences